# Order information is not displaying

Tags: magento-1.9, php, orders, error

I have order
[image]

When I click on one of the records

I got this
[image]

How can I solve this problem

Is this due to php version or other problem.

I am using php 5.3 and magento 1.9.

Please help.

Comment: Looks like you have a php error. Check your logs in var/log/ folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In index.php comment out below code.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Otherwise you can check view source error is located there where the actual problem.

**cntrl + u [view source]**

It will display error.

Comment: I did that no error found

Comment: cntrl + u [view source] I hope you will find error there.

Comment: Great I got the error, Thank you . Sorry I cant vote you up I have low reputation.